# In Adobe Fireworks CS4 how do I change document dimensions without cropping bitmaps contained in the document?

Tags: adobe-fireworks

If I am working with Bitmaps in fireworks their data behaves independently of the document area,  in other words I can move a bitmap in and out of the canvas without losing any of its data.  This gives me room to play about with part of the bitmap in visible areas.

But as soon as I crop the document, it crops all bitmap data to the confines of the canvas.  All I want to do is make the canvas smaller but still have the full bitmap to 'play' with inside the smaller canvas.   How do I crop a document without cropping all of its assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fireworks properties, `Ctrl + U` there's this option. **Uncheck it.**
[image]

I don't know of a quicker path to this option (Just saying because in photoshop similar option appears *after* you've drawn the cropping area, but in FW, not so much.).

---

---

Or From the top menu:

```
Modify > Canvas > Canvas size
```

Comment: Brill!  Thanks.    That will save me a lot of hassle.

Comment: I wish I would have known this trick years ago!  Thank you very much.